# Save view after execute command?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, ex-command

I'm mostly developing with python. I'm using pdbpp as python debugger so I'm contantly adding

```
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

or

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

So I wrote couple of functions.

```
function! AddBreakPoint()
    let l:line = line('.')
    let l:indentChar = ' '
    call append(l:line - 1, repeat(l:indentChar, indent(l:line)) . "import pdb;pdb.set_trace")
endfunction


function! RemoveAllBreakPoints()
    write
    silent! execute 'bufdo g/\v^\s+(import pdb|pdb.set_trace)/de'
endfunction
```

The problem with that now is that `RemoveAllBreakPoints()` messes relative position of cursor on the screen. So for example if the cursor was in the middle of the screen after `zz` it would be on the same line, but this line suddenly appears at the bottom of the screen.

EDIT1 OK, I solved it with KeepView plugin, but could someone explain to me why vim doing that and is there a native way to keep view after executing command?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a plugin for that, the functionality is built into Vim:

```
function! RemoveAllBreakPoints()
    let view = winsaveview()
    write
    g/\v^\s+(import pdb|pdb.set_trace)/d
    call winrestview(view)
endfunction
```

Reference:

```
:help winsaveview()
:help winrestview()
```

Comment: Oh, that I know. KeepView is just a function that decorates any other function with winsaveview() and winrestview().

Comment: So… why ask the question if you already know the answer?

Comment: I want to know exactly why this is happening, because I don't see any reasonable explanation.

Comment: That's the question you added, not the original question. Anyway, ex commands leave the cursor on the last "item" concerned by the command (line, buffer, window, tab page…). That means that you need to somehow record the current position if you want to come back afterward.